# Google apps script listbox event processing, undefined value

Tags: event-handling, listbox, google-apps-script

The idea of this apps script is to populate listbox LbxJobs based on the selected item in listbox LbxJobTypes.

I am getting an undefined value for e.parameter.LbxJobType which seems to be preventing conditional population of LbxJobs.

I successfully tested the handler(JobTypeValueHandler) by hard coding(I set JobType=T300_JOB_TYPE) JobTypeValueHandler function and the LbxJobs listbox populated as expected.

I do get "LbxJobType" when checking  e.parameter.source.  The listboxes were created in GUI builder.

```
var T200_JOB_TYPE = 1;
var T300_JOB_TYPE = 2;

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  app.add(app.loadComponent("BasicCalculator"));
  var Dischandler = app.createServerHandler('DiscClickHandler');
  app.getElementById('chbxDiscl').addValueChangeHandler(Dischandler);    
  return app;
 }


function DiscClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();   
  var Discpanel = app.getElementById('FLpnlDisc');

  BCalcSetup(app);
  Discpanel.setVisible(false);  
  return app;
}


function BasicClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  return app;
}


function BCalcSetup(app){
  var BCalcpanel = app.getElementById('APnlBCalc');  
  var lbxJobType = app.getElementById('LbxJobType'); 
  var JobTpyehandler = app.createServerChangeHandler('JobTypeValueHandler'); 
  var lbxJobs = app.getElementById('LbxJobs'); 

  JobTpyehandler.addCallbackElement(lbxJobType);
  lbxJobType.addChangeHandler(JobTpyehandler);
  lbxJobType.addItem('Title 200');
  lbxJobType.addItem('Title 300');
  loadClassifications(lbxJobs,T200_JOB_TYPE);
  BCalcpanel.setVisible(true);  
}


function JobTypeValueHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  var JobType=T200_JOB_TYPE;
  var lboxJobs=app.getElementById('LbxJobs');  

  if (e.parameter.LbxJobType=='Title 300'){JobType=T300_JOB_TYPE;}
  loadClassifications(lboxJobs,JobType);
  app.close();
  return app;
}


function loadClassifications(lbox,JobType){ 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);

  lbox.clear();
  if (JobType==T300_JOB_TYPE){
    var T3data =spreadsheet.getRangeByName('Title300Jobs').getValues();  
    for (var row1 = 1; row1 < T3data.length; row1++) {
      lbox.addItem(T3data[row1]);
    }
  }else{   
    var T2data =spreadsheet.getRangeByName('Title200Jobs').getValues();  
    for (var row2 = 1; row2 < T2data.length; row2++) {
      lbox.addItem(T2data[row2]);  
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: I feel kind of silly but I figured this out.

 The problem I had was I did not fill in the Name property for these listboxes when I created the interface in GUI builder. 

I went back into GUI builder and filled in the name property for each box and and now it works like a champ. 

Live and learn

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of silly but I figured this out. The problem I had was I did not fill in the Name property for these listboxes when I created the interface in GUI builder. I went back into GUI builder and filled in the name property for each box and and now it works like a champ. Live and learn